# resize disk capacity VDI

Tags: virtual-machine, vdi

I use virtualBox version 4.2.6 and I install windows server 2008. the issue is when I was working with this windows a message is displayed said that the capacity of disk  is limited. so I want to know if there is a method to increase the disk size.
thank

Comment: i try this method : **VBoxManage modifyhd YOUR_HARD_DISK.vdi --resize SIZE_IN_MB** but it doesn't work

Comment: please provide the error message you get when you attempt to resize the disk

Comment: 0%...
Progress state: VBOX_E_NOT_SUPPORTED
VBoxManage.exe: error: Resize hard disk operation for this format is not implemented yet!

Comment: I guess VM guest OS is not running

Answer (score 2):

Resize of VDI *is* supported, but you can only make hard disks bigger. You tried:

> VBoxManage.exe modifyhd "C:\Documents and Settings\User\VirtualBoxVMs\windows\windows.vdi" --resize 40

That means you try to make a 40 MB harddisk, your harddisk is bigger, though.
Try:

> VBoxManage.exe modifyhd "C:\Documents and Settings\user\VirtualBo x VMs\windows\windows.vdi" --resize 40000

This make new size 40 GB.

Answer (score 1):

Your vdi format does not support resizing. Maybe you could try cloning it to a new, larger vdi, possibly with a format that does support resizing. Have a look at the `clonehd` option of `VBoxManage` here http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-clonevdi

Then you can use the new, larger vdi in your virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but it just happened to me today and made me spent a lot of time searching for an answer, so I decided to post it here in case it happens to someone else.  
I was going to add a comment to @justTryToHelp's answer but I don't have enough points to do so.

So, as stated by @Steve, **disk as to be dynamic**.  
The "--resize" value **must be set to** [your_current_disk_size] + [space_to_add].  
Ex.: You created a disk with 25GBs and you need additional 9GBs => (25 + 9) * 1024= 34816  
cmd => VBoxManage modifyhd YOUR_HARD_DISK.vdi --resize 34816  
  
  
Hope this helps

**EDIT**
Don't forget to extend your disk in disk management.
Check this [link](http://jonmifsud.com/blog/increase-virtualbox-disk-size/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what ever type of file format the disk is stored in does not support resizing using the tool

Resize hard disk operation for this format is not implemented yet!

If the disk was set to Fixed and not dynamic that is probably the issue.

Comment: the disk is set to dynamic

Comment: can you paste the full command you are running.

Comment: **VBoxManage.exe modifyhd "C:\Documents and Settings\user\VirtualBo
x VMs\windows\windows.vdi" --resize 40**
0%...
Progress state: VBOX_E_NOT_SUPPORTED
VBoxManage.exe: error: Resize hard disk operation for this format is not implemented yet!

Answer (score -1):

This is a long shot but maybe try to the nearest 10gb?

Attempting to increase a 20gb .vdi to 25gb, and running the following command from C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox> (on version 4.3.12)...

```
vboxmanage modifyhd "D:\VirtualBox VMs\VS14 CTP\VS14 CTP-disk1.vdi" --resize 25000
```

...returned

```
0%...
Progress state: VBOX_E_NOT_SUPPORTED
VBoxManage.exe: error: Resize hard disk operation for this format is not implemented yet!
```

but when I increased the new size to 30gb..

```
vboxmanage modifyhd "D:\VirtualBox VMs\VS14 CTP\VS14 CTP-disk1.vdi" --resize 30000
```

It worked...

```
0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
```

I can't say anything else sensible to say at this point... :) At best the message is misleading.

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of justTryToHelp's answer.

Comment: @Ramhound. I'd assumed that the initial "resize 40" was in all likelihood smaller than the current size of the vdi, hence the error. In my case the new size was larger and failed. Upped it even larger and it worked again. I can see why you may think it's similar however.

Comment: You list the exact same commands.  The answer explains what the `40` stood for, 40 MB, so I am not sure where your confusion was.  As for the error message, its clearly the incorrect message, you likely tried to shrink the hdd smaller than its physical size on the host operating system.

Comment: What other command would I list? That is the command. As for the size I initially had the error attempting to increase a 17.5gb vdi to 25gb. Anyway, thank you for at least stating why you'd downvoted, most don't have the decency / spine to.

Comment: I am trying to strongly indicate that your answer is not that helpful, it adds no new information, and just repeats what was already suggested.  **Of course I didn't downvote your answer.**